# Randomizing effects on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

To keep it small and simple, when clicking a button, all the the divs should slide away in random directions and another set of new divs should be displayed.

Basic demo of what the jQuery code is like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#toggle_value").click(function(){
           $("#div1").show("fast");
           $("#div2").show("fast");
           $("#div3").show("fast");
        });
});
```

But its all about randomizing the effects. Any solutions?

Comment: "Another set of new divs"? Can you provide some html?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/8uKt3/13/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var $div = $('div'),
            pos = [0, 0, 0, 500, 250, 100, 50, -500, -750, -1000, -1500], // Define your numbers
            mypos1,
            mypos2,
            $me;

        $("#toggle_value").click(function(){
            $div.each(function(){
                $me = $(this);

                // Choose a value from each array randomly
                mypos1 = pos[Math.floor(Math.random() * pos.length)];
                mypos2 = pos[Math.floor(Math.random() * pos.length)];

                // animate in a random direction in a random quantitya
                $me.animate({
                    'top' : mypos1,
                    'left': mypos2
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: That would be my approach to, but I would use `Math.round(Math.random() * (pos.length-1))` instead of `Math.floor(Math.random() * pos.length)`, because your way has a very little chance that it will ever return the last element of the array (it will do so only when `Math.random() == 1`)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, lets say you have 3 possible cases for how the divs might slide away:

```
var rand = Math.random();
if (rand < .33) {
    // Some animation
} else if (rand < .66) {
    // Some other possible animation
} else {
    // Final animation possibility
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm:

- create an array of 'n' ints
- shuffle the array
- in the click function:

  - for each value 'v' in the shuffled array:

    - $('#div' + v).show('fast')

My guess is that you're going to have introduce a delay in the animation using the completion all back on 'effect' for this to look good, but that should be trivial to do